# How to have radio buttons with Materialize and WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, materialize, flask-wtforms

In Materialize you define the radio group of a radio button using the attribute `name`, but Flask-WTForms binds the input with an attribute `name`.

If I have the following in my template:

```
{{ form.radio1(type='radio', name='group1') }}
{{ form.radio2(type='radio', name='group1') }}
```

There will be an error:

```
TypeError: html_params() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

And if we don't add the name, the radios won't work as radios, just as checkboxes, as expected.

How can i get around this?

This is my form class:

```
class AbcForm(FlaskForm):
    field1 = HiddenField('Field1')
    field2 = HiddenField('Field2')
```

and then at runtime I'll dynamically add the radios, here's a simplification:

```
class F(AbcForm):
    pass

    setattr(F, radio1, BooleanField('Radio1')
    setattr(F, radio2, BooleanField('Radio2')

form = F(field1=x, field2=y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the `name` attribute in your field, wtforms already does that for you.

Use the [RadioField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.RadioField) instead of HiddenField:

```
from wtforms import RadioField
from flask_wtf import Form

class YourForm(Form):
    radio_group = RadioField('label', choices=[('value','description'),('value_two','some other description')])
    (...)
```

Then, in your endpoint:

```
@route('/your/route')
def your_endpoint():
    your_form = YourForm()
    (...)
    return render_template('/your/template.html', form=your_form)
```

Finally, in your template:

```
<form action="#">
    {% for subfield in form.radio_group %}
    <p>
        {{ subfield }}
        {{ subfield.label }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

This generates the following code:

```
  <form action="#">
    <p>
      <input id="radio_group-0" name="radio_group" type="radio" value="value">
      <label for="radio_group-0">description</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="radio_group-1" name="radio_group" type="radio" value="value_two">
      <label for="radio_group-1">some other description</label>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Which, given materialize is included in the template, will render the radio buttons properly as shown in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qutaW8tXld84H5PbaLE5?p=preview).

Comment: Doesn't really solve my issue:
the default widget {{ subfield }} won't work for materialize so i'll have to make it manually, and doing it manually i HAVE to set the name attribute because that's how materialize works to group a bunch of radios, even if i used a RadioField, it would still bring me to the same problem

Comment: It works as expected. Here's a plunker of the rendered template: https://plnkr.co/edit/qutaW8tXld84H5PbaLE5?p=preview Please follow the steps exactly as described and don't forget to include the materialize files in your template

Comment: Just edited the answer with the generated code and plunker. If you get different generated code from mine after following the steps please update your question with that so I can check it.